# Adressing variable using a string and an int in Arduino

Tags: variables, int, arduino

I wonder how I can **address a variable by putting together a string and an int** in Arduino.
I´m using many variables of the same type and with almost the same name. I´m just append a number to each variable.
The names of the variables are e.g. int sensorValue_1; int sensorValue_2; and so on.
I´d like to write less because my code is becoming too long.
When addressing the variables, I´d like to write something like this: sensorValue_**[+ intVariable]**;

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
int sensorIndex_1 = 1;
int sensorIndex_2 = 2;
int sensorIndex_3 = 3;

int sensorValue_1;
int sensorValue_2;
int sensorValue_3;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  doSomething(sensorIndex_1);
//doSomething(sensorIndex_2);
//doSomething(sensorIndex_3);
}

void doSomething(int sensorIndex)
{
  if(sensorIndex == 1)
  {
    Serial.print("Sensor 1: ");
    sensorValue_1 = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.println(sensorValue_1);
  }

  if(sensorIndex == 2)
  {
    Serial.print("Sensor 2: ");
    sensorValue_2 = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.println(sensorValue_2);
  }

  if(sensorIndex == 3)
  {
    Serial.print("Sensor 3: ");
    sensorValue_3 = analogRead(A3);
    Serial.println(sensorValue_3);
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

And I want to shorten the code in the doSomething() method. 
I want to have something like this:
Notice the "**[+ sensorIndex]**"

```
void doSomething(int sensorIndex)
{
  Serial.print("Sensor [+ sensorIndex]: ");
  sensorValue_[+ sensorIndex] = analogRead(A[+ sensorIndex]);
  Serial.println(sensorValue_[+ sensorIndex]);

  delay(1000);
}
```

By the way: I´d like to avoid for-loops, if possible.
In my case, the code would become too complicated.
How do I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User2461391 has a great start but the rest of the puzzle I think you want is:

```
int array1[3];
int array2[3];
int arrayx[3];


void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
   int index=1;

   array1[2]=doSomething(2);
   arrayx[index]=doSomething(index);
   Serial.print("Sensor ");
   Serial.print(index);
   Serial.print(": ");
   Serial.println(arrayx[index]);         

   while(1);
}

int doSomething(int sensorIndex) // It probably makes more sense to return the value
{         
      return  (analogRead(sensorIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `A1` and `A2` and the likes to define the analog pin you want to read. Just 1 or 2 will do.

```
void doSomething(int sensorIndex)
{
      Serial.print("Sensor ");
      Serial.print(sensorIndex);
      Serial.print(": ");
      sensorValue = analogRead(sensorIndex);
      Serial.println(sensorValue);

      delay(1000);
}
```